# How to do this grep regex

Tags: grep

I am trying to grep all lines that have two repeating numbers.

At first I tried `grep "[0-9][0-9]"` but this is just asking for lines with two numbers. How do I make it look for two numbers that are the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep -E '([0-9])\1+' <FILENAME>
```

The '[0-9]' is self-explanatory.

The '\1+' looks for 2 or more occurrences of the same character specified within the grouping

Comment: Add a '.' ie. grep -E '([0-9]).\1+' <FILENAME>. The '.' matches any character except a newline. Are you guaranteed one character in between? Remember regular expressions will only be a viable solution if your looking for a particular pattern.